# Schema.org - Microdata and JSON-LD behave diffrently for same code

Tags: html5, schema.org, microdata, json-ld

Having a hard time with JSON-DL and several blogPost. The way I see it, both Microdata one and JSON-DL one is exactly the same, yet the latter only show one blogPost, where Microdata show both.

HTML Microdata Markup:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Blog">
<header>...</header>
    <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <h1 itemprop="headline">Article Heading One</h1>
    </article>
    <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <h1 itemprop="headline">Article Heading Two</h1>
    </article>
</body>
```

JSON-DL Markup:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context":"http://schema.org",
        "@type":"Blog",
        "blogPost":{
            "@type":"blogPosting", 
            "headline":"Article Heading One"
        },
        "blogPost":{
            "@type":"blogPosting",
            "headline":"Article Heading Two"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Copy here to test:
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

Anyone see whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typcal... Tried several different methods for hours, and a few minutes after I ask here, I fix it myself...

Anyway, correct code for getting several blogPosts is this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context":"http://schema.org",
        "@type":"Blog",
        "blogPosts":
        [
          {
              "@type":"blogPosting", 
              "headline":"Article Heading One"
          },
          {
              "@type":"blogPosting",
              "headline":"Article Heading Two"
          }
        ]
    }
</script>
```

Will use it to markup every blog like a index site, guess that is what Its for :)

Comment: Apparantly I cant do that until 2 days. Just tried

Comment: That's weird. Usually it's 11 minutes or so after the question was asked. Must be more to it then I know.